# Page content moves behind sidebar, Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I've written a sidebar using Bootstap 5 which is placed on my _Layout view. The issue I'm having is when I load a new page like a users view, initialy it looks great, until I resize my screen and then the content on the users view slides behind the sidebar. I've tried placing the sidebar in a new column and row, etc but nothing I do seems to fix this. Below is my sidebar code, any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

```
<!-- Side Nav-->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="sidebar card py-2 mb-4 col-2 float-start vh-100 rounded-0 position-fixed" style="background-color: rgb(95,131,183); 
                width: 250px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px">
            <ul class="nav flex-column" id="nav_accordion">
                <li class="nav-item border-bottom">
                    <a class="nav-link bi bi-house" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" style="color:whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item border-bottom">
                    <a class="nav-link bi bi-gear" href="#" style="color:whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Settings </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item border-bottom">
                    <a class="nav-link  bi bi-speedometer" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Dashboard  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item has-submenu border-bottom">
                    <a class="nav-link bi bi-people" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Contacts  </a>
                    <ul class="submenu collapse" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px">
                        <li><a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="UsersIndex" style="color: whitesmoke"> Users </a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke"> Customers </a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke"> Suppliers </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                @*                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Something </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Other link </a>
                </li>*@
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div
```

Many thanks
AJ

Comment: I try to test your sample code on my side and I found that displays the sidebar after my page content. I could notice that you are using your custom CSS in the code that has `Position: fixed`. I would suggest you remove your custom CSS code and try to use the classes from bootstrap. Instead of a fixed nav bar. Try to make it a collapsible sidebar so that when you resize the screen, it will just collapse and will not overlap the page content.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT, thank you for your reply. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: You could let me know if you need further suggestions on the said issue. You could shared the updated sample code and we could try to provide you further suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT, appologies for the late reply, I've been a bit swamped. I'm trying to re-work my sidebar a bit. My plan is to make the side bar shrink or colapse as my screen shrinks. I've seen a couple of sampes online so will try and get that too work. I'll opst back a bit later with a new sample and any issues I have.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT, I've removed the "Position: Fixed" but now my pages load under my sidenav. No matter what i try, I cant seem to lock the sidenav in place so that my pages are contained. I cant seem to add the new code to these comments.